# Component not rendering fully and not changing with the change in State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement a basic React-Redux Counter App but for some reason it is not rendering fully, the normal html part is working but the **this.store.getState()**  in the render function is getting the value and isn't being rendered.I tried to find debug it first thing i found was when i tried console.log(this.store.getState()) it returned **undefined** and second thing i found was i didn't use **store.subscribe** to re-render the page everytime the state changes and i'm sure the problem has something to do with it but how to include **store.subscribe** when we are using class for rendering the view ?

This is the Code of **App.js** which contains the class Counter

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux'

class Counter extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.store=createStore(this.counterReducer);
    // this.store.subscribe(render);
  }
  counterReducer = (state=0,action) =>{
      switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
          return state+1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
          return state-1;
      }
  }

  counter = (props) =>{
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Value : {props.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={props.OnIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={props.OnDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.store.getState())
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <this.counter value={this.store.getState()} OnIncrement={() => {
          this.store.dispatch({
            type:'INCREMENT'
          })
        }} OnDecrement={() => {
          this.store.dispatch({
            type:'DECREMENT'
          })
        }
        }/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Counter;
```

This is the code of index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: must use react-redux

Comment: Redux with react uses a `connect` function as described [here](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), which serves to take the full Redux state and turn it into props that get passed into your component.

Comment: Now technically you don't HAVE to do that, but the alternative is subscribing to the Redux store in your `componentDidMount` and updating your component state every time a relevant change in the state happens, and then making sure to unsubscribe when you unmount - but most people prefer the `connect` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using useReducer from react directly.

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

const counterReducer = (state,action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
      case 'INCREMENT':
        return state+1;
      case 'DECREMENT':
        return state-1;
    }
    return state;
}
const CounterButton = (props) =>{
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Value : {props.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={props.OnIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={props.OnDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
const Counter = () =>{
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(counterReducer, 0);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <CounterButton value={state} OnIncrement={() => {
          dispatch({
            type:'INCREMENT'
          })
        }} OnDecrement={() => {
          dispatch({
            type:'DECREMENT'
          })
        }
        }/>
      </div>
    );

}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Since Redux Store is not local to a component this solution seems more appropriate. You can view how to configure the store here https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store